# Set default fetch size for Oracle JDBC driver without code modification

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

### Background

I'm writing a program that uses Oracle as a database.

I want to change the default fetch size for SQLs for performance, without code modification.

### Problem

The program uses SQL in various places, so I want to avoid inserting `setFetchSize()` before every `Statement.executeQuery()`.

With PostgreSQL or MySQL, you can change the default fetch size with the JDBC URL parameter `defaultRowFetchSize`. You can set `defaultRowFetchSize=100` to improve the performance of DB access.

However, I couldn't find the equivalent for the Oracle JDBC driver.

### Question

Is there any way to set the default fetch size for the Oracle JDBC driver without code modification?

### Note 1

This program accesses Oracle through `DataSource`. I can change the JDBC URL. I can also change system properties or environment variables without code modification.

### Note 2

The current implementation doesn't use `setFetchSize()` or `Properties` to set the default fetch size (it doesn't set any properties to call `Statement.executeQuery()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can specify a [`defaultRowPrefetch` property](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a83724/basic1.htm#1006248).

```
java.util.Properties info = new java.util.Properties();
info.put ("user", userName);
info.put ("password", passWord);
info.put ("defaultRowPrefetch", "15");
getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@", info);
```

Comment: The current implementation doesn't use `setFetchSize()` or `Properties` to set the default fetch size, so I have to add code everywhere in the code to do this. I have added a note to the question.

Comment: @SATOYusuke It works **exactly** the same as Postgres but the property name is different `defaultRowPrefetch` instead of `defaultRowFetchSize`. Add that to your url in the connection string. Edit your question to include how you currently get a `Connection`. I assumed you had that isolated.

Comment: Thank you for your information! I've read the document about JDBC Developer's Guide and Reference (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjdbc/), but couldn't find that information. I've googled `defaultRowPrefetch` and finally found the API document of `OracleConnection` says `All connection properties can be specified as a URL parameter` (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html).